# jQuery: Add class based on value of a slider / bootstra-slider.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I'm using **[bootstrap-slider.js](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider)** and I would appreciate if someone could help me add a function to add a class (.active) if the slider has a specific value (ex.1100) with jQuery

The class `active` should be added to an image or a div *(i'm using font-awesome icons as an example in the demo)*

my current js

```
$("#slider").slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
});

$("#slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#slider-val").val(slideEvt.value);   /* Changes the value of the input field with the slider value */

});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojdEBM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `if` statement to the slide handler to check if the slider value equals the specified value, and then use `addClass()` to add the active class to the elements.

I've assumed you want the active class removed if the slider is NOT at the specified value, which is what the `else` block does.  If you don't want it to be removed, then remove the `else` block.

```
$("#slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#slider-val").val(slideEvt.value);
    if (slideEvt.value == 1531){
      $('.fa-user').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.fa-user').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```